# Highlight files in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse, is it possible to highlight a file in the Package Explorer?

What I want is to highlight the operational classes (putting green for example, which means that I do not have to return above) to identify those that should be reviewed.

Or there is another way to identify visually some files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Try to look at [Label Decorator extension Point](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_decorators.html)
.

And you decorator should implements org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILightweightLabelDecorator. See also org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IDecoration

Comment: Thank you four your help. However I actually have no time and competence to develop an Eclipse plug-in, may be in later. So my question would be "Is a plugin already exists to do it?"